# how to get the max value from an input of having same class name using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I need to get the max value of the hidden input field of class name "numberoffield" using jQuery. Anyone can help me.

```
  $('.addTime1').click(function(){
   var $i = 0;
   $('<div class="fields"><input type="hidden" value="'+$i+'" id="hidden'+$i+'" 
   class="numberoffield" /></div>').slideDown('slow').appendTo('.inputs');
   $i++;
 });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "max value"?

Comment: "max value" mean whenever we click on "addTime1" the $i value will increase by one and I am storing the $i value in hidden input "numberoffield" in each time, So Ineed to get the final $i value from the hidden input

Comment: declare your variable i as a gloabal variable

Comment: Yes I got the solution. we can use :last like                         var $last = $('.numberoffield:last').val();

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".numberoffield").attr("maxlength")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get the value for each `input` in a element with class `'.fields'`, and save the highest value to `output`;

```
var output = 0;
$(".fields > input").each(
    function(){
        if(this.val() > output){
            output = this.val();
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

After your comment on your OP, here you go:

```
function getValue(){
    return $('#hidden').val()
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I got the solution. we can use :last like var $last = $('.numberoffield:last').val();